# How do I compute weighted average using summarise_each?

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I compute the weighted average of all the fields in a dataset using summarise_each in dplyr? For example, let's say we want to group the **mtcars** dataset by **cyl** and compute the weighted average of all columns where the weights are taken as the **gear** column. I've tried the following but could not get it to work.

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_each(funs(weighted.mean(., gear)))

# The line above gives the following output
# Error in weighted.mean.default(c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 4.15555555555556) : 
# 'x' and 'w' must have the same length
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To help see what's going on here. lets make a little function
that returns the lengths of it's arguments

```
lenxy <- function(x,y)
    paste0(length(x),'-',length(y))
```

and then apply it in `summarise_each`, as in:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_each(funs(lenxy(., qsec)))

#>   cyl   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec   vs   am gear carb
#> 1   4 11-11 11-11 11-11 11-11 11-11 11-11 11-1 11-1 11-1 11-1
#> 2   6   7-7   7-7   7-7   7-7   7-7   7-7  7-1  7-1  7-1  7-1
#> 3   8 14-14 14-14 14-14 14-14 14-14 14-14 14-1 14-1 14-1 14-1
```

Looking at this table, you can see that the lengths of
the first and second arguments are the same up until `qseq` and then 
afterword the second argument to `lenxy` has length 1, which is the result
of the fact that dplyr does operates on the data in place, replacing each
field with it's summary, rather than creating a new data.fame.

The solution is easy: exclude the weighting variable from the summary:

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(weighted.mean(., gear)),
                   -gear)
```