# How to get a mean of means in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have this data (a very simple example of what I’m really working with):

```
a <- data_frame(c(45, 50, 1), c('cats', 'dogs', 'giraffes'), c(1.5, 3, 15))
names(a) <- c('count', 'animal', 'avg_height')

  count   animal avg_height
  (dbl)    (chr)      (dbl)
1    45     cats        1.5
2    50     dogs        3.0
3     1 giraffes       15.0
```

I’m trying to use summarize to get the average height of the entire population. So I do this:

```
summarize(a, count = sum(count), avg_height = mean(avg_height))

  count avg_height
  (dbl)      (dbl)
1    96        6.5
```

That’s obviously not right, because we counted so many more dogs and cats. How do I convince summarise to consider the count when summarizing? Or is there a different function I should be using?

(I don’t believe this is a duplicate of [How do I compute weighted average using summarise_each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290062/how-do-i-compute-weighted-average-using-summarise-each) because it’s asking a substantially simpler question. The answer to this helped me; the answer to that other was over my head.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
summarise(a, avg_height = weighted.mean(avg_height, count))
#  avg_height
#1    5.35641
```

`weighted.mean` offers you to specify weights, in your case the frequency.