# 'Not Found' Error for weight trying to calculate weighted average with dplyr summarize_all

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate a weighted mean using dplyr and summarize_all.  I've seen similar questions, most specifically this post:
[How do I compute weighted average using summarise_each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290062/how-do-i-compute-weighted-average-using-summarise-each)

This seems pretty straight-forward but I keep getting an **object 'weight' not found** error message.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
data <- tibble::tribble(~group, ~weight, ~x1, ~x2,
                    1, 1, 3, 2,
                    1, 1, 4, 7,
                    1, 1, 1, 4,
                    2, 1, 2, 2,
                    2, 1, 5, 3,
                    2, 1, 4, 2)

# Just regular means
data %>%
      dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
      dplyr::summarize_all(mean)

# First attempt
data %>%
      dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
      dplyr::summarize_all(weighted.mean(., weight))

# Second attempt based on syntax from post above
data %>%
      dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
      dplyr::summarize_all(funs(weighted.mean(., weight)), -weight)
```

This is what happens when I run this code:

```
> data %>%
+   dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
+   dplyr::summarize_all(mean)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  group weight       x1       x2
  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1      1 2.666667 4.333333
2     2      1 3.666667 2.333333
> 
> data %>%
+   dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
+   dplyr::summarize_all(weighted.mean(., weight))
Error in weighted.mean.default(., weight) : object 'weight' not found
> 
> data %>%
+   dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
+   dplyr::summarize_all(funs(weighted.mean(., weight)), -weight)
Error in eval_bare(dot$expr, dot$env) : object 'weight' not found
```

Any information on why this is happening and what, if anything, I can do about it, is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by using `summarize_all` you're trying to also calculate the weighted mean for the `weight` column.

You're likely to be more interested in `summarise_at`:

```
data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
  dplyr::summarize_at(vars(x1, x2), funs(weighted.mean(., weight)))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  group       x1       x2
  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1 2.666667 4.333333
2     2 3.666667 2.333333
```

Comment: Thank you so much; I'm not familiar with the summarize_at but that's it exactly.  I'm going to need to learn more about these additional dplyr commands.